# Entity framework: one table, two entities - concurrency problem

Tags: .net, entity-framework

in our system we have one table, named Customer. And for some reason we have 2 entities referenced to this table, say Customer and AdditionalProperty.
I need to test something and I create entities, Customer and AdditionalProperty. But when I try to delete them I have the following exception: "**Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.**"

Could someone explain me what to do?
Thanks!